# Error: Cannot find module @ionic/cli-utils

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I'm trying to run ionic in terminal and am getting the following error:

```
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/cli-utils'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/dist/index.js:14:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

I've looked around on google but can't find any reason for the error. Any ideas?

Comment: You can just delete the node_modules folder and do some npm install again this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It also happened to me when updating new version. Solved It as:

1. Delete **node_modules**
2. Delete **package-lock.json** file
3. Run **npm install** command
4. ionic serve

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me when updating Ionic to it's latest version (currently 3.9.2).
Solved it doing the following:

- Delete `package-lock.json` file
- Delete `node_modules/` folder
- Edit `package.json` file dependencies and devDependencies sections to:

  ```
  "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
      "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
      "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
      "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
      "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
      "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
      "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
      "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
      "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
      "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
      "ionicons": "3.0.0",
      "rxjs": "5.4.0",
      "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
      "zone.js": "0.8.12"      
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
      "typescript": "2.3.4"
  }
  ```
- Run `npm install` again
- Edit script section in the `www/index.html` file:

  ```
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

what is your ionic's version? please type some ionic info
if is ionic3.x 
try npm i -g @ionic/cli-utils?
i solved it,